# <button> code and script in wordpress header.php not working for onclick action

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have some  code that was sent from a third party to add to our wordpress site. The button I am replacing (had no extra code) was in the menu but since this one contained javascript, I added it in the header.php after the menu. It doesn't work. I have also placed several of these buttons throughout the page and they work fine. The one in the header.php however will not do anything.

I tried adding the javascript in the header as opposed to the bottom of the button code. No go. I can see when I view the source code that there is an onclick action that shows up but it isn't in the original code. I tried putting that code directly in header.php, that didn't work wither.

```
<div id="meeting-button">

<!-- ScheduleOnce button START -->
<button id="SOIBTN_ELAMeeting" style="background: #ffab40; cursor: pointer;" data-height="580" data-psz="00" data-so-page="ELAMeeting" data-delay="1">Schedule a Meeting</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.oncehub.com/mergedjs/so.js"></script>
<!-- ScheduleOnce button END --></div>
```

This is the code that shows live with the onclick action----

```
<div id="meeting-button">

<!-- ScheduleOnce button START -->
<button id="SOIBTN_ELAMeeting" style="background: #ffab40; cursor: pointer;" data-height="580" data-psz="00" data-so-page="ELAMeeting" data-delay="1" onclick="return soe.toggleLightBox(&quot;ELAMeeting&quot;)" data-so-done="true">Schedule a Meeting</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.oncehub.com/mergedjs/so.js"></script>
<!-- ScheduleOnce button END -->
</div>
```

I am not great at javascript so not sure if I am missing something here. It works on the page just not in the header.php.

Comment: Can you provide the JavaScript? Your issue might be there rather than the execution HTML wise.

Comment: The javascript is coming from https://cdn.oncehub.com/mergedjs/so.js

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but I think your error is in the parsing of your function through `onClick="yourFunction()"` you passed through html entities: `&quot;` without the single/ double quotes to tell JS you want quotes. You could do `("\""+ELAMeeting+"/"")` or `('$quot;' + ELAMeeting + '&quot;')`
The first one negates the `"` in JS as a string value where it would typically throw an error for parsing with random quotations. The second one uses single quotes in a string to allow the html entity to be parsed.

Comment: ok, lemme try that, keep in mind this is all added in header.php file. Does that have anything to do with why it wouldn't work? Adding it directly into a php file?

Comment: ok, just tried your suggestions Jordan and that didn't work. The second set of code above is what shows live in the source code, the first is what is actually in the header.php file which seems to work anywhere else I put it except there.